# Listing specific software on group of remote machine

Tags: windows, command-line, ps

psinfo -s \10.101.4.204 > out.txt
above command displays all software installed on 10.101.4.204

I need to find only specific software installed on remote machine

Comment: What have you tried? If you need to confirm whether a specific program is installed, did you try searching for the name in psinfo's output?

Comment: i have tried below command                                                                         psinfo -s \\10.101.1.204 > out.txt

Comment: Yes, so now can't you check in out.txt whether that software is listed or not?